# how to switch level in variant m3u8 playlist when each playlist has independent Media Sequence Numbers

Tags: media-player, http-live-streaming, m3u8

playlist

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=150000,RESOLUTION=416x234, \
CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
level1.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=240000,RESOLUTION=416x234, \
CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
level2.m3u8
```

level1.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10,
level1-fileSequence1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
level1-fileSequence2.ts
```

level2.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:2
#EXTINF:10,
level2-fileSequence2.ts
#EXTINF:10,
level2-fileSequence3.ts
```

in level1.m3u8, the media-sequence-number of file 'level1-fileSequence2.ts' is 2

and in level2.m3u8, the media-sequence-number of file 'level2-fileSequence3.ts' is 3,

we assume that the two files have the same position in the presentation

now i want to switch level from level 1 to level 2 after download level1-fileSequence1.ts,

HOW could i know WHICH ts file to choose in level 2? OR we need more infomation?

Comment: It's media sequence + discontinuities if any + segment offset. `level1` is at index 1 (media sequence) + 1 (offset of fileSequence2) = 2. Since `level2` already has media sequence 2 then your corresponding segment would be the one at offset 0, so 2 = 2 + 0, so it's also fileSequence2.

Comment: @aergistal  we already assume that `level1-fileSequence1.ts` and `level2-fileSequence2.ts` present the same content as well as `level1-fileSequence2.ts` and `level2-fileSequence3.ts`. **Question1** IF we choose `level2-fileSequence2.ts` here, don't we load the same presentation twice?   what about if level2.m3u8 #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE=4 ? .  
 **Question2** if we download  `level2-fileSequence2.ts` , how do we compute PTS, we can't playback the same content twice?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example. `fileSequence2` and `fileSequence3` don't have the same position because the media sequence is different, like you said one is 2 the other is 3. Are your variants out of sync? To get the PTS you can parse the packetized elementary stream.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an old question, but these few added words might help somebody.

As I understand it, you can't really determine which segment to load from the information here. Consider that segment sizes don't need to be the same between levels.

When switching levels all you really have to go on to syncronize the video is the time elapsed since the most recent discontinuity, and that is contained in the timestamp. So like aergistal says, you're going to have to parse the ts to be certain which media file to choose.